# Objective C: trigger method at pan value

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipangesturerecognizer

What is the best way to trigger a `method` based on `Pan gesture` value?

I want to trigger a `method` when my `pan location x` is between 500 to 600. How do people normally handle this??

Answer (score 0):

You need to override gestureRecognizerShouldBegin. Then you can detect translation.x and see where the values fall between.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer {
   CGPoint translation = [panGestureRecognizer translationInView:self.view];
   if (translation.x > 500 && translation.x < 600)
      [self callCustom];
   return true;
}

- (void) callCustom {
 //do what you need to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a method that handles the pan gesture. Make that method look something like this.

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        CGPoint movement = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];

        if (movement.x >= 500 && movement.x <= 600) {

            [self methodToCall];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I only want to method to call once? say I want to launch specific UIView. With the suggestion you give, it will continue to call the method as long as your pan is still continueing. Thanks!

Comment: I'd use a `BOOL` variable that you set to `YES` the first time you call the method, and then set an if condition that only calls your method if your variable is set to `NO`